# OpenStreetMap relation ID rarely present

Tags: openstreetmap

first off, I'm not looking for any 3rd party parsers or existing libraries. I've also read all related OSM questions on StackOverflow and haven't seen an answer.

I'm looking to parse the OpenStreetMap data into a viable structure for rendering and routing and had a quick question about this. To this end I exported a tiny portion of the center of a major city, and have it parsed to a usable structure.

The Relation-XML looks like this:

```
<relation id="31249" visible="true" version="100" changeset="13180178" timestamp="2012-09-20T08:12:17Z" user="Skywave" uid="10927">   
<member type="way" ref="22375740" role=""/>   
<member type="way" ref="39271187" role=""/>   
<member type="way" ref="39271189" role=""/> 
<member type="way" ref="39271191" role=""/> 
</relation>
```

.. etc

But these ref-IDs are often not present in the XML. Ideally they'd refer to another node, another relation.. but often they only occur in this one line. This essentially means it's worthless info, correct?

I suspect OSM includes all known information, and if that information happens to be outside the map area, its reference in relations is still included but the actual object that is referred to is not exported along, and I can trim it out ?...

Tried to find this on the OSM website.. couldn't :-)

Comment: What is your actual question? If the ID's are worthless? _Why_ does it matter if they are? What is the _actual_ problem you are facing with them? Also I don't see any reference to XSLT so you probably don't need that tag. Unless you left something out in which case you should edit your question.

Comment: You post that existing solutions don't work for you: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks  
Why exactly and why do you spend time on developing a OSM XML parser on your own?

Comment: I didn't mention open solutions didn't work for me, I mentioned I'm not looking for one.

As for the IDs being worthless, it matters to me because I want to clean up the file, and I wanted to double-check my assumption was correct

Comment: They are not worthless of course. They are required for downloading the corresponding elements if you need them.

Comment: Of course. :-) They are not useful in my scenario, but 'worthless' was a bad way to put it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSM extracts from APIs etc. don't contain all elements that are linked in a relation. They contain all geo objects (nodes, ways) that touch the boundingbox of your extract. But for relations it doesn't work like this, just because otherwise in a worstcase it will cascade (relation links to other relations or huge ways that are present in multiple relations...) till a huge mass of objects (even without the bbox) need to be present in the extract.

You might use bigger extracts that you can make sure to contain all data (e.g. country planet.osm extracts) or call an read-only API like Overpass API to get the objects.

Answer (score 0):

The Overpass API is the way to go. To extract all nodes related to you given relation you would need to do a query like this:

```
relation(31249);
>;
out;
```

See: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/41k

To only select way members (with their node ids) of the given relation run:

```
relation(31249);
way(r);
out;
```

The Overpass API is quite confusing at first but really powerful.